# unable to create a directory path using ansible unarchive module?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to download and extract a tar archive in the remote machine and remote destination must be created if not exists. BUT it is not happening.

> ERROR: destination directory doesn't exist

MYCODE:

```
- unarchive:
    src: http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.15/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.15.tar.gz
    dest: /opt/tomcat/
    creates: yes
    remote_src: True
```

NOTE:
* running the play as root.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think the directory should be created?

Comment: `creates:` is not meant to be taken literally. Check the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html). `creates:` job is not to create a new directory tree or path; it is used as a conditional checkpoint to execute the task only if a certain **file** *does not exist*. Also see the couterpart, `removes:`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While using the unarchive module, the dest path should be a path to an existing directory, and creates should be a path to a file and not a boolean.

```
- name: ensure tomcat directory exists
  file:
    path: /opt/tomcat
    state: directory

- unarchive: 
    src: http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.15/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.15.tar.gz
    dest: /opt/tomcat/  # already existing path
    creates: /opt/tomcat/config  # some path to make sure that the archive has already been unpacked
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: hi @deepak i just specified dest: /opt creates: /opt/tomcat. But it is not creating tomcat directory in that. it is directly unzipping files into /opt

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, dest should be an existing path. You have to create the directory before unarchive. updated the answer

Comment: yes @deepak.. i completely understand your point. that's why i changed "dest" as /opt which is always exist in linux. then i wrote creates:  /opt/tomcat . so according to your answer it should create tomcat directory. right??

Comment: No @Harish.K, I think tux means you have to use the "file" module to create opt and tomcat. And you would not use creates in unarchive at all, since it's not meant to be used for directories.